# Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $R$ and let $f_n (x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$. Prove that ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Tags: calculus

> **Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ and let $f_n(x)=f(x+\frac{1}{n})$. Prove that ${f_n}$ converges uniformly to $f$**.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$, I have $\forall \epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\forall x,y \in\mathbb R$,$|x-y|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Now I try to find $f(x)$ by taking $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)$. How can I do this, if I apply $n\rightarrow\infty$ into $f_n$, I got $f(x)=f(x)$ which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Given $\epsilon>0$, choose $\delta>0$ so that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. Now choose $N$ with $1/N<\delta$.  Then for $n\ge N$ and for any $x$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makes **all** the sense, because **proving** $f_n\to f$ uniformly is the objective of the problem. You have proved the pointwise convergence (and that $f$ is the only **possible** uniform limit).

For the uniform convergence, use the uniform continuity of $f$ in following:
$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f(x+1/n)-f(x)|\le\cdots.$$

Comment: you want me to use the triangle inequality here? $|f(x+1/n)-f(x)| \leq |f(x+1/n)-f(y)|+|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x+1/n)-f(y)|+\epsilon$?

Comment: Not required in the case, $|f(x+1/n)-f(x)|$ is already $|f(x)-f(y)|$ for $x=\cdots, y=\cdots$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Could you please complete last line?

Comment: @Priya, see the comment by David Mitra.